# EV3G Where can I find the .vix file for the low-level functions? (Set integer, IO operations, start block)

Tags: programming, software, ev3-g

They look like this:

[image: Image of low-level functions]

By default, when you refer to a vix file, it looks like this:

`<Reference Type="VILib" Name="TerminalTerminal.vix" />`

But, to refer to these low-level functions, you need to write:

`<Reference Name="X3.Lib:StartBlockTest" Type="VILib" SubType="StartBlock"/>`

Where can I find this "X3.Lib"?

Thanks in advance,
Csabi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LEGO *EV3 Block Developer Kit* documentation refers to these as "gray blobs". These are compiler intrinsics and don't have a .vix implementation. They generally correspond directly to the bytecodes from the *EV3 Firmware Developer Kit*.

---

Note: Developer kits are available on the official LEGO MINDSTORMS [download page](https://www.lego.com/en-us/themes/mindstorms/downloads).

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what i was looking for!
I didn't except to get an answer so quickly, since most of the questions here are about Lego minifigures, but it's nice to know there are also people like you, that know a lot about the EV3 brick

Comment: The main reason I asked this question, is because the Start block seemingly has a "result" output. Do you have any idea what thats for?

Comment: I think the start block is a little different that other blocks since it starts a VM thread instead of calling a specific bytecode command. The output is probably just the program flow wire that connects to the next block to run.